# How to use integral to get the marginal mean.

Tags: probability, integration

### The Question

> Suppose that the conditional distribution of $Y(t)$ given $X$ is
>
> $$Y(t)|X \sim N(t+X \exp(-tX),1).$$
>
> The conditional mean of $Y(t)$ given $X$ is $t+X \exp(-tX).$ Suppose also that the marginal distribution of $X$ is unit exponential. The marginal mean of $Y(t)$ is obtained by integrating out the covariate to get
>
> $$\mu(t)=E[t+X \exp(-tX)]=t+\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}.$$

### My Understanding

As stated in the figure below, we want to figure the expected value of $Y$ via integrating out the $X$. I followed the law of the unconscious statistician but cannot get the result provided by the author. Also I m not sure if the unit exponential means the pdf of $x: f(x) = e^{-x}$. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Yes, unit exponential has pdf $f(x)=e^{x}, x>0$. Please show what you have done so far.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy: your density has a divergent integral ;)

Comment: @tommik Sorry for the typo. I meant $e^{-x}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [law of total Expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_expectation)

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=[\mathbb{E}[\mathbb{E}[Y|X]]=\mathbb{E}[t+xe^{-xt}]=t+\mathbb{E}[xe^{-xt}]=t+\int_0^{\infty}xe^{-xt}\cdot e^{-x}dx$$

---

to solve the integral without a lot of calculations observe that

$$\int_0^{\infty}x e^{-x(t+1)}dx=\frac{1}{(t+1)^2}\underbrace{\int_0^{\infty}[x(t+1)] e^{-x(t+1)}d[x(t+1)] }_{=\Gamma(2)=1}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I was stuck at recognising the gamma function, much appreciated.